# java.util.zip.ZipException: File too short to be a zip file

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I m working in android studio (the latest version), and while trying to read my firestore data :

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("user-grp").document("1");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

getting this error ( though my app is running fine on device ). plz help sort out this. the logcat is showing this :

```
E/System: java.util.zip.ZipException: File too short to be a zip file: 0
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:161)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:98)
    at libcore.io.ClassPathURLStreamHandler.<init>(ClassPathURLStreamHandler.java:47)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.maybeInit(DexPathList.java:532)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.findNativeLibrary(DexPathList.java:546)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findLibrary(DexPathList.java:480)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findLibrary(BaseDexClassLoader.java:84)
    at xtr.a(:com.google.android.gms@214815020@21.48.15 (040406-414534850):6)
    at xtr.g(:com.google.android.gms@214815020@21.48.15 (040406-414534850):4)
    at xtr.f(:com.google.android.gms@214815020@21.48.15 (040406-414534850):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.ProviderInstallerImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms@214815020@21.48.15 (040406-414534850):6)
    at com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.ProviderInstallerImpl.insertProvider(:com.google.android.gms@214815020@21.48.15 (040406-414534850):5)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.insertProvider(:com.google.android.gms@214815020@21.48.15 (040406-414534850):2)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:12)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(GrpcCallProvider.java:99)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6$com-google-firebase-firestore-remote-GrpcCallProvider(GrpcCallProvider.java:256)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.call(D8$$SyntheticClass)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$com-google-firebase-firestore-util-ThrottledForwardingExecutor(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java:54)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(D8$$SyntheticClass)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is produced by this code? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Also getting this, but when calling ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplication());